# Laravel 5.8 @if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->role_id == 2) returns an error

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

The piece of my navbar I'm having issues with:

```
@if(Auth::user()->role_id && Auth::user()->role_id == 2)
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Manage My Ad Images</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">My Ads</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Post an Ad</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Reload My Account</a>
@endif
```

And I'm getting a "Trying to get property 'role_id' of non-object" error.

I've tried with Auth::check() as well, and it made no difference.

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id && Auth::user()->role_id == 2)
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Manage My Ad Images</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">My Ads</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Post an Ad</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Reload My Account</a>
@endif
```

Comment: Can you show how you've tried with `Auth::check()` because clearly the user is unauthenticated hence the reason of having the exception. Calling a property on a `null`.

Comment: See edit above @nakov :)

Comment: try doing the `@if(Auth::check())` before, and then nest the other conditions `@if(Auth::user()->role_id && Auth::user()->role_id == 2)`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I just gave it a try - got the same error. I've never seen this issue before, and build most of my projects on Laravel.

Comment: If you added the `Auth::check()` condition, and still get the same error, then either you did not save the file, you are editing a different file than the one that produces the error, or you are looking at old error-logs. Doing `@if (Auth::check() ...)` *will* work. If you check all those boxes, you can clear your view-cache by doing `php artisan view:clear`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Your nested solution worked. I knew there was something weird happening. It didn't seem to stop at evaluating the first half of the statement. Could you post an answer so I can get you your well-deserved credit?

Comment: glad to know it works. I added the answer

Comment: @Qirel file was saved, and that check still performed in the same way, but only returned the false once I seperated it into two nested evaluations. I'm anal about saving files, so it was definitely not this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if there an authenticated user with `@if(Auth::check())`, and then nest the other conditions:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    @if(Auth::user()->role_id && Auth::user()->role_id == 2)
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Manage My Ad Images</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">My Ads</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Post an Ad</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Reload My Account</a>
    @endif
@endif
```